# Type cast issue for [Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

```
  public List<Client> findClientByAssociateUser(String userId) {
        logger.info("Enter find list of clients by this user");
        org.hibernate.Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("SELECT c.id, c.clientName, c.billingAddress,c.contactNumber"
                + " from Client c, User ud"
                + " WHERE ud.id = c.userId and ud.id = :id")
                .setString("id", userId);
        List<Client> result = (List<Client>) query.list();
        logger.info("Exit find list of clients");
        return result;
    }

public ModelAndView userDetails(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mvc = new ModelAndView();        
    List<Client> clientList = userRepository.findClientByAssociateUser(id.toString());
       mvc.addObject("clientList", clientList);
       for (Client client : clientList) {
        System.out.println("Client Name{" + client.getClientName());
    }
    mvc.setViewName(MANAGEUSER_PREFIX + "details");
    return mvc;
}
```

I am getting:

```
Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Client
```

Comment: o\can u show your stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type in the query would be `List<Object[] >.`

Because your query says

```
SELECT c.id, c.clientName, c.billingAddress,c.c......
```

change

```
List<Client> result = (List<Client>) query.list();
```

and then process according to that

to

```
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
```

or change the query to

```
   SELECT c from Client c......
```

Comment: @Talha Bin Shakir did you see my solution.Try this it will be the problem